# RESTful API is working but not rendering UI correctly (MDC + Sheetsu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, google-sheets

I'm using a service called [Sheetsu](https://sheetsu.com) that turns a Google Sheet into a `RESTful API` *(pretty bad ass!)*. Anyways, I'm using it in combination w/ the [MDC Library](https://material.io/components/web/docs/) (Material Design Components) but my UI isn't rendering properly because the service brings in the data after it's already ran my JS. MDC provides the function `mdc.autoInit()` that will auto initialize the components, and this works great for a static website..but isn't enough for my use case.

I've got a dirty hack making this work right now.. but I'm searching for the proper way. Can anyone tell me how to properly initialize my **MDC Components** with **Sheetsu**?

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/qxayvY

---

**HTML:**

```
<section sheetsu="https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/1ea3e5b69776">
    <div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
         <input type="{{TYPE}}" class="mdc-text-field__input" id="{{ID}}">
         <label for="{{ID}}" class="mdc-text-field__label">{{LABEL}}</label>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS:**

```
<!-- Libraries -->
<script src="//load.sheetsu.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    mdc.autoInit();
    dataBind();
  }, 1000);
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to *somewhat* get this working, but I'm sure there's a better way. Posting this answer here to hopefully help someone else :D

The issue was the data was being loaded **after** everything else.., so by using the `$.when()` and `$.done()` methods in combination w/ `setTimeout`, I was able to achieve the goal.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/oneezy/pen/qxayvY

```
  function applicationFILE() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/c6876062929d"
        // dataType: "json",
        // data:  yourJsonData
    });
  }

  function testFILE() {
      return $.ajax({
          url: "https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0su/1ea3e5b69776"
          // dataType: "json",
          // data:  yourJsonData
      });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.when(applicationFILE(), testFILE()).done(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        mdc.autoInit();
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
```